# In Google Sheets, how to lock or prevent sorting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a shared Sheet that multiple people edit. The data is in a very specific order for our needs. I need to prevent people from sorting this sheet which messes up the data. I am open to an Apps Script or settings-based solution.

Protecting the sheet really isn't an option as so many ranges take edits from numerous people

Ideally, the sort menu item will be grayed out. Secondarily, override the sort button to have no action. Alternatively, have code to do something like cancel the sorting action or reverse the sort.

Comment: Do you have an example of code you've tried?

Comment: In all my research of the API, I have not found anything like a Menu class that works on the default menu items that would allow me to disable the menu item. Only for custom menus.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to add a protected column that contains item numbers in the desired order and resort the sheet on every edit.  Possibly you could check to see if there are items out of order first.  This may not be practical if it's a big sheet.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, it counts the number of rows and locks them from sorting

```
function freezeRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getDataRange().getValues().length;  //gets # of rows

  ss.setFrozenRows(range);//freezes all rows
}
```

can use the onOpen and onEdit triggers so whenever it's opened it's ran, and also runs when anything is edited.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out how to limit some users to sort the entire sheet or even sort a column. If you want to restrict user "JOHN" you need to :

1. Give him editor rights to the sheet.
2. Create an empty column (let's say it's column A)
3. Click Data. Protected sheets and ranges. Restrict JOHN from editing column A.

> When John will try to sort the sheet or a column, instead of being sorted, it will create a temporary filter because he has not access to the entire sheet :)

You can also deny him access to the sheet's first line (or create an empty one), so he cannot filter any column (you need to have access to the entire range to do so)

Let me know if that works for you as well!